# Directories - Why is this erroring out?

Tags: python, directory, adventure

I am building a few directories for a program I am working on, but they keep erroring out when used within the game and without of it. Each line throws out the same error (`Syntax Error: invalid syntax`) and I am wondering why. The lines are:

```
secretpassageunearthed = 'No'
pickedup = {'broom': '0', 'rope': '0', 'torch': '0', 'coffin': '0', 'skeleton' = '0', 'key2': '0', 'rock': '0', 'key1': '0', 'mailbox': '0', 'instructions': '0', 'letter': '0', 'key3': '0', 'oar': '0', 'boat': '0', 'red button': '0', 'eaglenest': '0', 'faberge egg': '0', 'trophy case': '0', 'facial': '0', 'gun': '0', 'safe': '0', 'diamond ring': '0', 'junk': '0', 'combination': '0', 'egg': '0', 'flashlight': '0', 'cork': '0', 'bottle': '0', 'oil': '0', 'crown': '0', 'shovel': '0', 'knob': '0', 'twinkies': '0', 'scanner': '0', 'toychest': '0'}
#has the player been in the room?
beenin = {'frontdoor': '0', 'forest': '0', 'forest2': '0', 'forest3': '0', 'forest4': '0', 'lakeshore': '0', 'garden': '0', 'shed': '0', 'lake': '0', 'farshore': '0', 'cliff1': '0', 'cliff2': '0', 'cliff3': '0', 'cliff4': '0', 'clifftop': '0', 'frontsteps': '0', 'frontlawn': '0', 'gate': '0', 'sittingroom': '0', 'livingroom': '0', 'pantry': '0', 'foyer': '0', 'trophyroom': '0', 'hall1': '0', 'diningroom': '0', 'kitchen': '0', 'elevatorup': '0', 'hall3': '0', 'hall2': '0', 'masterbed': '0', 'closet': '0', 'nursery': '0', 'bath': '0', 'guestroom': '0', 'study': '0', 'secretroom': '0', 'servantdining': '0', 'servantbath': '0', 'servantroom': '0', 'boilerroom': '0', 'mechanicalroom': '0', 'winecellar': '0', 'deadend': '0', 'torturechamber': '0', 'morgue': '0'}
maxweight = 50
weights = {'broom': 5, 'rope': 8, 'torch': 5, 'coffin': 40, 'skeleton': 9, 'key1': 2, 'key2': 1, 'rock': 4, 'instructions': 0, 'mailbox': 60, 'letter': 1, 'gargoyle': 60, 'key3': 1, 'blockade': 60, 'oar': 5, 'boat': 30, 'button': 1, 'eagle nest': 60, 'faberge egg': 10, 'trophy case': 60, 'book': 3, 'facial': 1, 'gun': 3, 'safe': 60, 'diamondring': 5, 'junk': 1, 'combo': 1, 'egg': 1, 'flashlight': 3, 'oil': 4, 'bottle': 3, 'cork': 1, 'chandelier': 60, 'crown': 5, 'shovel': 5, 'knob': 3, 'twinkies': 2, 'pot of gold': 30, 'painting': 20, 'scanner': 60, 'toychest': 55}
```

Any help on why they are erroring out would be appreciated.

Comment: `'skeleton' = '0'` is not legal syntax in Python's dict literal.

Comment: Also, those are _dictionaries_, not _directories_.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `=` to assign in a dictionary

Change `=` to `:` and this should work:

```
secretpassageunearthed = 'No'
pickedup = {'broom': '0', 'rope': '0', 'torch': '0', 'coffin': '0', 'skeleton' : '0', 'key2': '0', 'rock': '0', 'key1': '0', 'mailbox': '0', 'instructions': '0', 'letter': '0', 'key3': '0', 'oar': '0', 'boat': '0', 'red button': '0', 'eaglenest': '0', 'faberge egg': '0', 'trophy case': '0', 'facial': '0', 'gun': '0', 'safe': '0', 'diamond ring': '0', 'junk': '0', 'combination': '0', 'egg': '0', 'flashlight': '0', 'cork': '0', 'bottle': '0', 'oil': '0', 'crown': '0', 'shovel': '0', 'knob': '0', 'twinkies': '0', 'scanner': '0', 'toychest': '0'}
#has the player been in the room?
beenin = {'frontdoor': '0', 'forest': '0', 'forest2': '0', 'forest3': '0', 'forest4': '0', 'lakeshore': '0', 'garden': '0', 'shed': '0', 'lake': '0', 'farshore': '0', 'cliff1': '0', 'cliff2': '0', 'cliff3': '0', 'cliff4': '0', 'clifftop': '0', 'frontsteps': '0', 'frontlawn': '0', 'gate': '0', 'sittingroom': '0', 'livingroom': '0', 'pantry': '0', 'foyer': '0', 'trophyroom': '0', 'hall1': '0', 'diningroom': '0', 'kitchen': '0', 'elevatorup': '0', 'hall3': '0', 'hall2': '0', 'masterbed': '0', 'closet': '0', 'nursery': '0', 'bath': '0', 'guestroom': '0', 'study': '0', 'secretroom': '0', 'servantdining': '0', 'servantbath': '0', 'servantroom': '0', 'boilerroom': '0', 'mechanicalroom': '0', 'winecellar': '0', 'deadend': '0', 'torturechamber': '0', 'morgue': '0'}
maxweight = 50
weights = {'broom': 5, 'rope': 8, 'torch': 5, 'coffin': 40, 'skeleton': 9, 'key1': 2, 'key2': 1, 'rock': 4, 'instructions': 0, 'mailbox': 60, 'letter': 1, 'gargoyle': 60, 'key3': 1, 'blockade': 60, 'oar': 5, 'boat': 30, 'button': 1, 'eagle nest': 60, 'faberge egg': 10, 'trophy case': 60, 'book': 3, 'facial': 1, 'gun': 3, 'safe': 60, 'diamondring': 5, 'junk': 1, 'combo': 1, 'egg': 1, 'flashlight': 3, 'oil': 4, 'bottle': 3, 'cork': 1, 'chandelier': 60, 'crown': 5, 'shovel': 5, 'knob': 3, 'twinkies': 2, 'pot of gold': 30, 'painting': 20, 'scanner': 60, 'toychest': 55}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the problem is that you used `=` instead of `:` to assign a dictionary item.

When you saw the error message, you may not have noticed that Python was trying to tell you exactly where the error was:

```
  File "adventure.py", line 1
    pickedup = {'coffin': '0', 'skeleton' = '0', 'rock': '0'}
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

See how the `^` is pointing right at the equals sign?

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone for finding the mistake. I am fairly new to Python and am learning and Stack Overflow has been an invaluable resource. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

The [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id19) recommends keeping lines < 72 characters. Personally, I aim for 78. If you do that, your code is easier to read and as a bonus, its easier to spot problems. So for example, if you file was

```
secretpassageunearthed = 'No'
pickedup = {'broom': '0', 'rope': '0', 'torch': '0', 'coffin': '0',
'skeleton' = '0', 'key2': '0', 'rock': '0', 'key1': '0', 'mailbox': '0',
'instructions': '0', 'letter': '0', 'key3': '0', 'oar': '0', 'boat': '0',
'red button': '0', 'eaglenest': '0', 'faberge egg': '0', 'trophy case': '0',
'facial': '0', 'gun': '0', 'safe': '0', 'diamond ring': '0', 'junk': '0',
'combination': '0', 'egg': '0', 'flashlight': '0', 'cork': '0', 'bottle': '0',
'oil': '0', 'crown': '0', 'shovel': '0', 'knob': '0', 'twinkies': '0',
'scanner': '0', 'toychest': '0'}
```

You'd see that python points exactly at the problem

```
td@mintyfresh ~/tmp $ python3 test.py
  File "test.py", line 3
    'skeleton' = '0', 'key2': '0', 'rock': '0', 'key1': '0', 'mailbox': '0',
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You basically said "I wrote code that is hard to read and can't find the error".